# Does a quick decision mean refusal?

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, applications, application-status

I've submitted my application on Tuesday, yesterday it was received by the UKVI and today it says that a Decision was made. Is that too fast? does this necessarily imply refusal? It is worth mentioning that I've paid extra for 5 business days process but still 2 days seems fast, so what do you guys think? should I be prepared to receive a refusal or is that irrelevant?

Comment: You cannot predict it. Bayesian theory tell us. But lack of required document, refusal could be very short. But also by very good application. And sometime consulate are fast. (so many quick positive answers [as absolute number, not as percentage])

Comment: _Either_ refusals or approvals can be quick to make if the case is clear enough. It is the grey-area ones in the middle that can require additional time.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is a variant of post-submission anxiety.

Comment: Sometimes Stack Exchange community works in weird ways. There are 8 up-votes on a comment calling for the question to be closed but not even 4 actual close votes. If you like the question to be closed why not close it for the same reason as the comment above?

Comment: @HankyPanky: Hello from HNQ! I don't have close votes. I also haven't cast any sort of votes at all on this page, but I imagine others coming from HNQ might have voted. Also, the close flag dialog doesn't seem to have Musonius's custom close reason in it, or at least I didn't find it. I imagine more regular users of this site who also can't close vote may also have upvoted Musonius's comment.

Comment: @user2357112 that surely makes sense.

Answer (score 20):

It doesn’t mean anything other than the fact that your application was straightforward and decision was relatively easier to make.

You paid for Priority services and they did exactly what they claim about the service

> If you need your visa in a hurry, you can use UK Visas and Immigration’s Priority Visa service for your visit, work or study application.
>
> This will put your application at the front of the queue at every stage of the decision-making process.

[VFS Global](https://www.vfsglobal.co.uk/au/en/premium-services/priority-visa)

They have done a good job! Unfortunately even the clerk who returns your passport to you will not have a clue about the actual decision until the package is opened.